# Split a paragraph into lines in ZSH

Tags: string, shell, zsh

How can I take a multi-line string in zsh, and split it into an array of strings that are a single line each?

Specifically I want to take the output of cal

```
      June 2010     
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
       1  2  3  4  5
 6  7  8  9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16 17 18 19
20 21 22 23 24 25 26
27 28 29 30
```

and turn it into

```
("      June 2010     " "Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa" "       1  2  3  4  5"  " 6  7  8  9 10 11 12" "13 14 15 16 17 18 19" "20 21 22 23 24 25 26" "27 28 29 30")
```

Which is a zsh array.

---

My ultimate goal is then to take the output of another command and put them side by side, so if i had

```
a
b
c
```

and

```
d
e
f
```

I would end up with

```
a d
b e
c f
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an example of process substitution which will work in zsh and Bash. It uses the Unix/Linux tool `paste` to put two calendars side-by-side as a demonstration.

```
$ paste <(cal 6 2009) <(cal 6 2010)

     June 2009               June 2010
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa    Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
    1  2  3  4  5  6           1  2  3  4  5
 7  8  9 10 11 12 13     6  7  8  9 10 11 12
14 15 16 17 18 19 20    13 14 15 16 17 18 19
21 22 23 24 25 26 27    20 21 22 23 24 25 26
28 29 30                27 28 29 30
```

To answer your question directly:

```
saveIFS=$IFS; IFS=$'\n'; array=($(cal 6 2010)); IFS=$saveIFS
```

Which also works in Bash.

Comment: Second semicolon may be omitted.

Comment: Actually, saving and restoring IFS as well: IFS=$'\n' array=($(cal 6 2010))

Comment: @rocky: No, assignments don't work that way. If you test what you posted, you'll see that `IFS` is not restored. That works in the case of a "simple command", e.g. `IFS=$'\n' read -r var`.

Answer (score 7):

In zsh, you may type

```
array=( ${(s.
.)"$(cal)"} )
```

or, with eval:

```
eval $'array=( ${(s.\n.)"$(cal)"} )'
```

Here `(s.smth.)` specifies the expression to split on (no patterns, only fixed string. Unlike IFS, `(s.:::.)` will split on `:::`, while `IFS=':::'` will split on `:`). `eval` is used in order to put newline character inside `(s)` flag since `(s.\n.)` means split on backslash followed by letter «n».

Comment: Or just `${(f)"$(cal)"}`. The `f` is the same as `ps:\n:`. The later also shows how to use “escapes” with `s` without resorting to `eval`.

Comment: Your first one doesn't work for me (I get everything in one array element), unless I quote the command substitution: `"$(cat)"` the way **Chris** did in the comment above.

Comment: @Chris Johnsen thanks, forgot about `p` and did not know about quoting. Maybe you should post your own answer?

Comment: Err, I meant `"$(cal)"`, but you got it.